# Login and edit OSM in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, editing

Is there a way (e.g., with a plugin) to log into my OpenStreetMap account within QGIS and edit maps there?

Comment: not sure that exists but https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/osm_sidewalkreator/ is a creator of geojson (then can be imported via JOSM)